# Themes or Look and feel on PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

How to change the look and feel or the colors of all in PL/SQL Developer? Because for current time, it's hard to work wheb all in black!

Comment: so bad if there is no way to switch to black theme?

Comment: Really late to the party but I came across this dark theme: https://github.com/ozmoroz/ozbsidian-sqldeveloper.

Answer (score 5):

Head over to `Tools` -> `Preferences`. From there you'll be able to change the editor as well as the syntax highlighting colours.

[image: editor]

[image: Syntax highlighting]

Comment: Does exist any theme? i don't want change every thing in my self..i didn't find how change the design of TreeNode..

Comment: @DannyMichaeli ... I'm not sure I understand what you mean by treenode. No themes exist, you'll need to change it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I found this themes on github: https://github.com/cepruo/plsql-color-schemes
and this in the forum http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=56714&page=2